# How many ions in 1.00 mol of NaCl

Tags: ions, mole

it's my first week of IB chem and I'm already confused. We learned how to find the number of atoms, but not specifically ions... is it the same? Similar? HELP

Comment: Is it in an aqueous solution?

Comment: @can-ned_food That's is completely irrelevant.

Comment: You want to use the stoichiometry of the compound and Avogadro's number.

Comment: @Zhe With all respect due, it is not irrelevant if it helps us understand the asker's confusion.  It seems like there at least some here.  This is someone pursuing an educator's curriculum, not a chemist's.

Comment: @can-ned_food That specific issue doesn't help the OP answer their question, nor does it change the answer. It would be great if we didn't ask questions that may further confuse the issue by introducing variables that are not relevant to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 2):

$1$ $\ce{NaCl}$ contains $1$ $\ce{Na+}$ and $1$  $\ce{Cl-}$.

$1$ mol $\ce{NaCl}$ contains $1$ mol $\ce{Na+}$ and $1$  mol $\ce{Cl-}$.

$1$ mol ions = $6.02*10^{23}$ ions.

$1$ mol $\ce{NaCl}$ contains $6.02*10^{23}$ $\ce{Na+}$ and $6.02*10^{23}$ $\ce{Cl-}$.